# li click event not working

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I am creating a search box using li and input text.

I want to load a page based on the selected results of search box, whenever the search result is clicked.

Search result is in form of li on which I am binding the below click event.

Somehow the following click event is not firing

```
$("li").click(function(){
    alert("HI");
    alert($(this).text());
    return false;
});
```

See the JS Fiddle for more details:

http://jsfiddle.net/amitsant/2zhk209v/3/

Comment: $ is jQuery, in that fiddle you don't have jquery loaded...

Comment: Since you are showing and hiding the ul on focus/blur of the searchbox the list will hide itself before the click event hits the li element (see updated version here http://jsfiddle.net/2zhk209v/5/ )

Comment: and you deleted the first line from your javascript, which was presumably something like jQuery(function ($) {.  you have the closing }) though.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to include the first line of JSFiddle javascript... jQuery is not needed to load in JSFiddle I guess it automatically links JQuery and JQuery UI...

Comment: @ingo : Is there a way to have the click even working with the search implementation I had before?

Comment: this causes the malfunction `display` => `.search .results {  display: none;....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just listen to `mousedown` instead of `click`. This happens because click waits for the `mouseup` event, that never is triggered because `blur` comes first, hiding the panel.

```
$("li").mousedown(function(){
...
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3umj3fup/